# MissingPluginError: The atoti-jupyterlab plugin is missing, install it and try again

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, atoti

I am pretty new to working with atoti. While running the code 
`session.visualize('exploration 1')`

I am encountered with the error

```
MissingPluginError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Users\DIKSHA~1\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_17816/2587889388.py in <module>
----> 1 session.visualize('exploration 1')

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\atoti\_type_utils.py in typechecked_func_wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    184 
    185             # Call the actual function.
--> 186             return self._func(*args, **kwargs)
    187 
    188         # Mark the function as typechecked and return it.

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\atoti\_base\_base_session.py in visualize(self, *args, **kwargs)
     33         self, *args: Any, **kwargs: Any
     34     ) -> Any:
---> 35         raise MissingPluginError("jupyterlab")
     36 
     37     @property

MissingPluginError: The atoti-jupyterlab plugin is missing, install it and try again.
```

I have installed 'atoti' by using
`pip install atoti[jupyterlab]`
But still continue to be encountered by this error.

Answer (score 0):

You can:

- Check that the version of `atoti` and `atoti-jupyterlab` are the same.
- Restart the Jupyter kernel so that it can pick up newly installed dependencies and try again.